# Iteration for insert into values

Tags: postgresql, loops, plpgsql, common-table-expression, jsonb

I will try and present the current setup as an abstract view, the focus being on the logical approach to batch insert.

```sql
CREATE TABLE factv (id, ..other columns..);
CREATE TABLE facto (id, ..other columns..);
CREATE TABLE dims (id serial, dimensions jsonb);
```

The 2 fact tables share the same dimensions, but they've got different columns.

There's an event stream which send messages to a table and there's function which is executed for each row, the logic is similar to:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_event() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
IF event_json ->> 'type' = 'someEvent' THEN 
    WITH factv_insert AS (
      INSERT INTO factv VALUES (id,..other columns..)
      fn_createDimId,
      NEW.event_json->>..,
          ...
      RETURNING id
      )
    INSERT INTO facto VALUES (id,..other columns..)
    (select id from factv_insert),
    NEW.event_json->>..
ELSE DoSomethingElse...
END IF;
RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

The function called in here `fn_createDimId` just looks up the `dims` table and if these dimension are not found, they're inserted. If those are already in there, just give me that id for those dimensions as the id for this fact insert.

I do have some new events coming through and I need to grab some information which breaks the rules around insert into..values with `ERROR: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression`

The event structure is similar, but not limited to

```
{
    "type": "someEvent",
    "instruction": {
        "contains": {
            "id": "containerid",
            "map": {
                "50561:null:null": {
                    "productid": "50561",
                    "quantity": 3
                },
                "50562:null:null": {
                    "productid": "50562",
                    "quantity": 8

                },
                "50559:null:null": {
                    "productid": "50559",
                    "quantity": 5
                }
            }
        },
        "target": {
            "50561": "Random",
            "50562": "Random",
            "50559": "Mix",
        }
    }

}
```

What is causing the problems here is the information around `target` and the respective quantities for those ids. From the event shown above, I need to aggregate and insert into the fact table:

```
-------|-----
target | qty
-------|-----
Random | 11
Mixed  | 5 
-------------
```

If I was to query to grab the information, I would run the following:

```sql
WITH meta_data as (
SELECT
        json_object_keys(event_json -> 'instruction' ->'target') as prodid
        ,event_json -> 'instruction' ->'target'->>json_object_keys(event_json -> 'instruction' ->'target') as target
        ,event_json -> 'instruction' ->'contains'->'map'->json_object_keys(event_json -> 'instruction' ->'contains'->'map')->>'quantity' as qty
FROM event_table ) 
select
      target,
      sum(qty::int)
from meta_data
group by target;
```

I am looking to find a solution which makes it possible to do the same logical operations, but overcomes the error on the multiple returned rows, ideally an iteration for each event which returns more than 1 row.